# Testing methods in abstract classes with arguments

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In my TDD project I am trying to test a method in an abstract class.

```
abstract class Database_Mapper_Abstract
{

    public function setTable($sTablename){
        return('foo');

    }
}
```

This is the way I wrote my simple test:

```
public function testCanSetTable(){
        $oMock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract');
        $oMock->expects($this->once())
              ->method('setTable')
              ->with($this->equalTo('foo'))
              ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));
        $this->assertEquals('foo',$oMock->setTable());
    }
```

When I run this test i get the following error:

> PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> E
>
> Time: 1 second, Memory: 6.75Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   Database_Mapper_AbstractTest::testCanSetTable
>   Missing argument 1 for
>   Database_Mapper_Abstract::setTable(), called in
>   K:\xampp\htdocs\tests\library\Database\Mapper\Abstract.php
>   on line 15 and defined
>
> K:\xampp\htdocs\library\Database\Mapper\Abstract.php:4
>   K:\xampp\htdocs\tests\library\Database\Mapper\Abstract.php:15
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0,
>   Errors: 1.

The way I understand this is that it can't find the argument for the setTable function.
But I set it with the `with()` method. I also tried `with('foo')`. That also doesn't help me.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't know this testing framework but what happens if you change `$this->assertEquals('foo',$oMock->setTable());` to `$this->assertEquals('foo',$oMock->setTable('foo'));`

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't mock class under test. Because the code above does not test if the method setTable will return 'foo', it *defines* that the method setTable will return 'foo'. Mock objects are for passing them as arguments to classes under test, so you don't need to create large object graph for meet the dependencies.

Comment: When i do that i get this error: Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:setTable> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Testing an abstract class:

For testing an abstract class you don't want to use the "create behavior methods".

Just `getMockForAbstractClass()` like this:

```
<?php
abstract class JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract
{

    public function setTable($sTablename){
        return $sTablename."_test";

    }
}

class myTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testCanSetTable(){
        $oMock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract');

        $this->assertEquals('foo_test', $oMock->setTable('foo'));
    }

}
```

You just use the mocking functionality to create an instance of that abstract class and test against that.

It's only a shortcut for writing

```
class MyDataMapperAbstractTest extends JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract {
    // and filling out the methods
}
```

---

## The actual error:

What happens is that you have a method with one parameter:

```
public function setTable($sTablename){
```

but you call it with zero paremters:

```
$oMock->setTable()
```

so you get an error from PHP and if PHP throws a warnings PHPUnit will show you an error.

Reproduce:

```
<?php
abstract class JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract
{

    public function setTable($sTablename){
        return('foo');

    }
}

class myTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testCanSetTable(){
        $oMock = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract');
        $oMock->expects($this->once())
              ->method('setTable')
              ->with($this->equalTo('foo'))
              ->will($this->returnValue('foo'));
        $this->assertEquals('foo',$oMock->setTable());
    }

}
```

Results in:

```
 phpunit blub.php
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) myTest::testCanSetTable
Missing argument 1 for JCMS_Database_Mapper_Abstract::setTable(), called in /home/.../blub.php on line 19 and defined
```

## Fixing

Change:

```
$this->assertEquals('foo',$oMock->setTable());
```

to

```
$this->assertEquals('foo',$oMock->setTable('foo'));
```

then you don't get a PHP Warning and it should work out :)

Comment: I did this and removed the whole fluent interface part and then it works.  THe only thing is that i dont understand then why I need that Fluent interface stuff.

Comment: @sanders Updated my answer to reflect that. You don't, i might have misunderstood you in chat when i told you you would. Sorry if thats the case

Comment: @sanders - You use `expects()` to tell the mock object what to do when it receives that method call or that it should fail the test if it doesn't receive it. In your case, you want to test the real method and what it returns so you don't need an expectation. Instead, just use an assertion on the return value.